# PHP How can I split li items from a ul list by class?

Tags: php, parsing, split, html-lists

I am trying to use Simple DOM Parser, to parse each **li** item in the **ul** list by the class name. Below you can see the code I am trying to parse, but keep in mind it's from a html source code, just selected the code I want to parse.

I have tried with this PHP code, but it doesn't work at all..

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$url = "http://www.pinterest.com/avast/";

$html = file_get_html( $url );
$first_level_items = $html->find( '.userStats', 0)->children();

foreach ( $first_level_items as $item ) {
print_r($first_level_items);
}
```

This is the ul list I want to get the li items from.

```
<ul class="userStats">

<li>
<a href="/avast/boards/" type="button" class="NavigateButton Button Module ButtonBase hasText borderless active BoardCount">
<span class="buttonText">    
  13 opslagstavler    
</span>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="/avast/pins/">
<div class="PinCount Module">
  317 pins    
</div>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="/avast/likes/">
  1 synes om    
</a>
</li>

</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an xpath query instead?

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($your_ul_html);
$result = $xml->xpath('//ul[@class="userStats"]/li');
foreach($result as $node) {
    print_r($node); // or echo $node-asXML();
}
```